# For $U := G_{\alpha}\cap G_{\beta}$ there exists an involution in $N_G(U) \setminus U$ when the number of fixed points in $G$ is bounded by $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite, transitive, faithful group acting on $\Omega$ such that each nontrivial element has at most two fixed points.

*Lemma*: If $\alpha \in \Omega$ and $1 \ne X \le G_{\alpha}$, then for the subgroup $N_{G_{\alpha}}(X) = N_G(X) \cap G_{\alpha}$ we have $|N_G(X) : N_{G_{\alpha}}(X)| \le 2$.

*Proof*: Let $1 \ne X \le G_{\alpha}$ and $g \in N_G(X)$, then $X = X^g \le G_{\alpha^g}$, and so $\alpha^g$ is fixed by $X$, i.e. $N_G(X)$ acts on the fixed points of $X$. But $X$ has at most two fixed points, so either $N_G(X) \le G_{\alpha}$, or it induces the symmetric group on two points on the two fixed points of $X$, i.e. we have a surjective homomorphism $\rho : N_G(X) \to S_{\{\alpha,\beta\}}$, where $\beta$ denotes the other fixed point, with kernel $N_{G_{\alpha}}(X)$ and hence $|N_G(X) : N_{G_{\alpha}}(X)| = |S_{\{\alpha,\beta\}}| = 2$. $\square$

> Now suppose we have $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega$ distinct, and $U := G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\beta} \ne 1$. Further let $|G_{\alpha}|$ be odd and $|\Omega|$ be even with $(|G_{\alpha}|,|\Omega|) = 1$ and suppose $G$ has no subgroup of index at most $2$ that is a Frobenius group. Then why this implies that there exists an involution $x \in N_G(U) \setminus U$?

The above Lemma and our hypothesis about $G$ that it does not contain a Frobenius group of index at most $2$ should somehow give that $|N_G(U) : U| = 2$, and this in turn should imply that there exists such an involution. But I do not see how these facts are connected?

Comment: You haven't defined $U$ in the statement of the lemma. Is $U=X$?

Comment: Yes, this was a typo!

Comment: If this is a step in a published proof, then I suspect again that you might not have supplied enough information. What is the source of these proofs?

Comment: Yes, it is from the paper *Transitive permutation groups where nontrivial elements have at most two fixed points* by Magaard and Waldecker, specifically Lemma 2.25. The paper could be found on the authors page: http://conway1.mathematik.uni-halle.de/~waldecker/MagaardWaldecker2fp.pdf, or on sciencedirect: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404914000966, I do not see what I have forgot...

Comment: It doesn't say this in the proof, but the statement seems to follow from Lemma 2.1.  We know that $|N_G(U):U|=1$ or $2$. If $N_G(U)=U$ then, since all nontrivial elements of $U$ fix only $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we have $N_G(V) \le N_G(U)$ for all nonrivial subgroups $V$ of $U$ and so it follows by applying Lemma 2.1 with $H=U$ that $G$ itself is a Frobenius group with complement $U$. Hence $|N_G(U):U|=2$.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you, that it is much clearer now! But why do we have the involution $x \in N_G(U) / U$? All I see is that in that case $x$ interchanges $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but not that it must have order $2$?

Comment: Since $|U|$ is odd, $x$ must have order $2k$ with $k$ odd, and then $x^k$ has order $2$.